# How to make regular expression for Dreamwaver find and Replace?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, replace

I have the following code in about 300 HTML files, I need to replace it with some other code. But the problem in following code is the ID `click=12FA863` is change and different in each file, I want to use the regular expression which will work in Find and replace in Dreamwaver.

```
<iframe src="http://example.net/?click=12FA863" width=1 height=1 style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute"></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put

```
<iframe src="http://example\.net/\?click=[^"]+" width=1 height=1 style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute"></iframe>
```

in your find field and whatever you want to replace it with in your replace field and you should be set.

Comment: Forward-slashes and equals signs have no special meaning in a regex; you don't need to escape them.

Comment: In perl forward-slashes are often the separation characters for the regex string so I'm used to escaping them. Not sure why I had an escape on one of the equals and not the others. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial on Dreamweaver's Regex.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html

Comment: Can you suggest me the expression like:

[Start Text] [Anything] [End Text]

So that I can search like:

<iframe src [Anything] </iframe>

Comment: This link no longer functions.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you said in your comment, you want to replace

```
<iframe src [Anything] </iframe>
```

Then this will do:

```
<iframe src.+</iframe>
```

Where "." means "any character" and "+" means "1 or more of them"

If you *care* about the click ID value, or some other part, you'd want to capture it, like so:

```
<iframe src.+click=([A-F0-9]+).+</iframe>
```

and use $1 (or $2, $3, etc. if you add more) when replacing.

Note that [A-F0-9]+ just means "one or more hex characters"

So if you used that regex, and this as the replacement:

```
<div>something else using $1</div>
```

Then

```
<iframe src="http://example.net/?click=12FA863" width=1 height=1 style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute"></iframe>
```

Would become

```
<div>something else using 12FA863</div>
```

I'd definitely spend some time at the tutorial Daniel recommended, and also look at other Regex tutorials, cheat sheets, etc. such as [visibone.com/regular-expressions](http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe.+?</iframe>
```

This is a lazy regexp, that looks for the finisher tag `</iframe>`.

This regexp doesn't care where the `src` is, it will find `<iframe width... src=.. ></iframe>` too.